# Google Chrome - New tab - bookmarks - How to restore deleted ones?

Tags: google-chrome

I have accidentally deleted some of the book marks that show up on my 'new tab' page (recently visited / popular I guess).

[image: Chrome New Tab page]

How can I restore deleted links to this page? Or, how can I add new ones?

<sub><sup>Windows 7, Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m</sup></sub>

Comment: If you have not closed chrome then you **might** be able to restore the previous version by grabbing the backup file but if you have closed the instance the bookmarks are already gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost impossible to restore that. 
One possibility could be: Everytime  you install a new windows-update, windows sets a restore-point. So when you have installed an update short time, before you have deleted them, you can restore to the last restore-point and hopefully, the bookmarks will be restored. But be aware: Everything else that you have done after this restore point will be deleted. But if it's worth for you, give it a try.

[How to restore to a restore-point.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore)

Comment: Note: This is no longer the best answer.  As of version 33 this is possible.  See Andrew Lott's answer below.

Answer (score 34):

I've just found how to restore these, at least in `Version 33.0.1714.0 canary`.

Click the x to "Don't show on this page" for another link. You should get options below to **Undo** or **Restore all**. The **Restore all** brings back all links that have previously been hidden.

[image: Chrome New Tab page]

Comment: "Restore all" doesn't seem to restore removed links before closing down chrome though (atleast the latest version on Mac Os X).

Comment: Note that `Restore all` will show only after you delete something, so if you deleted something earlier, you need to delete another item in order to be able to restore them all.

Comment: Note that you should scroll down a bit on some screens.

Comment: Just tried this, not working for me anymore, version 46.0.2490.80 m

Comment: Just worked for me. Why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: On Windows 10, okt. 2017, this no longer works: no 'restore all' button appears. Not even an 'undo' button. With the result that now I've deleted several often used sites. :(

Answer (score 0):

you could also try Previous versions of Users folder on C:\ drive. Go to C:\Users\ = right click on your user name and go to Previous versions tab and select the date you want to restore the folder to. It should list multiple dates.

Note: this works only if the system protection is turned on.

Answer (score -1):

If you remember what bookmarks you had, and want to restore (or, more to the point, if you know what bookmarks you want to have now), go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and
delete all data from there. Your Chrome browser will be like a newly installed one. Then if you go to your favorite sites three or four times, they will appear on the “new tab” page.