# With the new version of chrome, how do I restore my "frequent views" on new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Since chrome did an update, how do I restore frequently viewed pages?

It relates to this question, but the restore/undo options aren't available to me for some reason: [Google Chrome - New tab - bookmarks - How to restore deleted ones?](https://superuser.com/questions/651279/google-chrome-new-tab-bookmarks-how-to-restore-deleted-ones)

Comment: Its missing because the version that screenshot is against is 3 years old.

Comment: @Ramhound That's why I'm asking "How do I do it in 2016"?